# How to give a group by default to a new contact?

Tags: contacts, groups

I'm a new user testing CiviCRM 4.6.2 with WordPress 4.2.2.

I have users U1, U2... belonging respectively to groups G1, G2...

I would like that when user U1 creates a new contact, this contact would automatically be added to group G1. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to do it with profiles. You can automatically add contacts to a specific group when they are entered via profile. Create two different profiles for your two groups, and have your users enter all contacts through their own profile page in Profile-Create mode. However, if you find yourself needing to create a unique profile for *every* user, then it's time to re-assess the need. An extension would be better at that point.

Answer (score 3):

You can create smart groups for this:

- Go into **Search > Advanced Search** and then open the **Change Log** pane.
- Select the **Added** option and enter the first user's sort name (yes, this ought to be improved) like "Smith, John".
- Run the search, and you should see the contacts he or she has created.  (Adjust the search if you need.)
- At the top of the results, select **All __ results** and then select **New Smart Group** in the Actions drop-down.
- Give your new group a name and save it.

Now, everyone that person creates will be added to that group.  Repeat this process for each of the users/groups you've got.

Comment: What if this person edits contacts they didn't create, or other people edit the contacts created by this person?

Comment: If you selected Modified in the search, it would pick them up, but I think selecting Added would solve this person's needs.

Comment: Agreed. Missed that.

Answer (score 2):

[CiviRules](http://redmine.civicoop.org/projects/civirules/wiki/TestingScenarios) isn't released yet, but this would be simple to implement as a rule.  If you need it now, and the other answers don't suffice, it would also be a very quick extension to write.